# How do I use an API to extract to CSV?

Tags: microsoft-excel, csv, api

Sorry, I've tried reading up on it but I just don't understand any of it.

There is an organisation, ALISS.org, which has a section with their API that lets you interact with their database of local community groups and support groups.

I'm trying to figure out a way to use this API to extract it all as a CSV so I can use it for some work I'm doing - I need to identify groups and match them against existing lists of funding options so I can link them together to help these groups get funding in their areas.
I just don't know how to do it. I have found some websites that let me load in the API, but I only get some sample returns.

I'm really sorry for asking this, I'm sure it's straightforward but I think it's just a bit beyond my capabilities. Any help is greatly appreciated!

I should add, my work system is pretty locked down so Excel etc doesn't have any fancy capabilities to let me do anything with it as far as I can see.

Kindest,

C

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: API's usually have documentation on how to use it in conjuncture with something like powershell or another scripting language. That scripting language can then put it into a CSV.

Comment: @LPChip Thank you for your comments! I've looked on the website, but I don't see documentation as such, unless you mean the sections in there?

https://api.aliss.org/swagger/ui/index#/

I do have PowerBI and I think I saw somewhere that I can put in an API to the Web data source section, but I've tried that with:

https://api.aliss.org/v4/organisations

but it doesn't give me anything other than one line telling me how many organisations there are, when I want each one listed with all entry details held against it.

Sorry for taking your time up with this!

Comment: Yes, that is indeed the API. They are queries that return data. Its up to you to tie it all together. SuperUser is not the site to ask help about this. Maybe google can tell you how to query an API using PowerBI.

Answer (score 1):

Based on your comment you probably didn't go far enough. I put in a search parameter of computers and hit the `Try it out!` button. It gave me the url: https://api.aliss.org/v4/organisations?searchTerm=computer

[image]

I then put that in power query/power bi > from web (you may need to choose anonymous). And I got data populating. I leave the rest up to you to which ever format you choose to CSV.